# Lost rebuilding state after every reboot on server with raid controller P410i/zero memory

Tags: windows, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, raid-controller

I have installed a server HP Proliant ML350 with P410i RAID controller with Zero memory, (windows 2008 standard running).
I have set up Raid 1+0 with two hard disk SAS and, as usually, I tested raid pull one hard disk. After that, I insert in the array hard disk. 
After 12 hours I check the rebuilding state and it was at 99%. I reboot the server for maintenance and I found rebuilding state at 0%!
I think it could possible becouse raid controller has no memory so that at every reboot, if it running a rebulding operation, lost its configuration of reconstruction; is it true my hypothesis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hypothesis is not true. The memory (or lack of memory) on the controller is used to buffer or cache read and write operations. The controller you have has no memory and is simply less performant than a model that does have cache memory. This should have no effect on the ability of the array to rebuild (other than the speed of the operation).

Also reference the [Smart Array Configuration Guide from HP](http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c02289065/c02289065.pdf).